# How to prevent calling a function depending on generic constraints in typescript?

Tags: typescript

As an exercise I'm implementing simple algebraic data types in typescript.
I would like to implement the `ap` function, in such a way that it is only callable when the wrapper contains a function.
This is how I would have liked to use it:

```
Identity.of(x => x + 1).ap(Identity.of(5)); // This should work and return an Identity(6)

Identity.of(5).ap(...); // This should make the compiler emit an error
```

I tried to define it with generic conditional like this:

```
type Func<T, U> = (p: T) => U;

interface Identity<T> {
  map<U>(fn: Func<T, U>): Identity<U>;
  ap<U, V>(id: Identity<U>): T extends Func<U, V> ? Identity<V> : never;
}

function of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
  return {
    map: fn => of(fn(value)),
    ap: id => id.map(value)
  };
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'Identity<V>' is not assignable to type 'T extends Func<U, V> ? Identity<V> : never'.(2322)
input.ts(5, 3): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Func<U, V>'.
```

Is this in any way possible to do in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After brute forcing for a long time, I have found a way to make this type safe:

```
type Func<T, U> = (p: T) => U;

interface Identity<T> {
  map<U>(fn: Func<T, U>): Identity<U>;
  ap(id: T extends Func<infer U, any> ? Identity<U> : never): T extends Func<any, infer U> ? Identity<U> : never;
}

function of<T>(value: T): Identity<T> {
  return {
    map: fn => of(fn(value)),
    ap: id => {
      const fn: unknown = value;

      return id.map(fn as Func<unknown, unknown>) as T extends Func<any, infer U> ? Identity<U> : never;
    }
  };
}
```

Infering the types in the interface definition helps typescript save types when chaining operations and makes everything type safe.
When writing the implementation we have to help typescript by using typecasts.